# Do I still need a third party tool to manage Azure development storage?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-storage

I'm finding my feet with Windows Azure, using .NET MVC5 and VS 2013. When I programmatically create blobs, I can use Server Explorer in Visual Studio to browse my development storage and see what's been added. I can't seem to delete things, for some reason. The VS UI locks up and I have to restart.

I read some (old) things online that say VS explorer is readonly, but I'm a bit confused as to why I can right click on a blob and "delete" appears in the context menu, yet doesn't work.

Lots of older tutorials recommend third party tools for managing Azure storage, but I don't understand why such basic stuff doesn't come out of the box with Visual Studio.

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683677.aspx

Comment: I dont find any problem in deleting blobs or tables from development storage using VS 2013. Which version of SDK are you using, try with 2.2 version. Also what do you mean by doesn't work? Any error? Also check VS logs and Windows logs, if you can find some information there.

Answer (score 0):

The older VS Explorer plug in was indeed read-only, but that is no longer the case.  You should be able to delete a file out of BLOB storage without a problem.  I just tested it to verify I didn't see a the same behavior.  Can you try on a different computer as well?

You may try using Fiddler (decrypting the HTTPS traffic) to see if the calls are actually being made to do the delete.  Also, as a commenter indicated, check the windows logs for any errors.

As to needing a third party tool for storage development, I'm a little biased since I work for Cerebrata and we sell Azure Management Studio, but there are things that the VS Explorer just doesn't do yet, or is made simpler by one of the tools.  You may find that the VS Explorer out of the box has everything you need (especially now that it's not read-only).  When many of the original tutorials were written there wasn't a VS Explorer plug in at all.  If you get everything you need from the VS Explorer plugin then you're all set.  If not, then my advice is to look at what the various tools offer and try them out.

Comment: Mark Rendle put up the following link to a variety of tools you can check out if the VS Explorer doesn't meet your needs: http://storagetools.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

This question seems way old but if someone is still stuck with the same question (Actively looking for a third-party tool to manage your Azure development storage), there are various reasons why third-party tools are a good-to-go.

The first thing is, all-in-one-place-management is still something I would bet Azure is still not aiming for. For managing all of your Azure resources, how time consuming is it to navigate X times to do a simple check of statistics, delete, etc? The next thing is automation - Purging blobs/files/messages based on user condition (Say purge blobs older than X days). Though there are options like [Lifecycle Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview) within the portal itself, I couldn't find a common area for my Azure Storage management with ease.

Storage Explorer is a tool from Azure that solves various problems I've mentioned above. Personally, I would recommend not looking beyond [Cerebrata](https://cerebrata.com/features/azure-storage?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=third-party-tool-manage-azure-storage).

***Just if you need***

The tool is cost-effective and provides users the capability to create, list, update & delete resources (blob containers, file shares, queues, tables & more).

The tool also provides capabilities to perform advanced operations like uploads/downloads, bulk operations, transfers, and more.

Hope you found it helpful.

Comment: Obviously visual studio has an option too. Storage explorer and Cerebreta manages everything in one place.